# Correct syntax to select datetime from a table

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM reservation 
WHERE USERID = "sinia.cabrera@laestanciaschool.com"
AND RESERVATIONDUEDATE = '2017-03-21 09:35:00'
```

It throws the following error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'ANDRESERVATIONDUEDATE=2017-03-2109:35:00 LIMIT 0, 30' at line 4

So far, I've tried to change the quotes from the date, the format and everything but its datetime and that's how it is displayed. Any ideas what might be going on?

**EDIT**

Apparently it's not an actual mysql syntax error, somehow the table is stuck with that query because I can access any other table and query them in any way I want, however this specific table (reservation) is stuck with that query no matter what I try to do. A service restart/stop didn't work.

Comment: are you running this query directly in the db or is it in a php code or so? BTW datetime is not the issue. Mysql is telling you the error is before. No space between `AND` and `RESERVATIONDUEDATE`. Also note that mysql is case sensitive on column names

Comment: @LelioFaieta - I think you meant to say mysql **CAN** be case sensitive, not **IS** case sensitive on column names.

Comment: @JuveLeo1906 please make me an example on when the table or column names are not case sensitive in a query.

Comment: @LelioFaieta On a Windows hosted Mysql server, table names are not case sensitive.

Comment: @LelioFaieta - There are plenty of cases when column names are case insensitive in queries...for example in MySQL 5.0, MyISAM engine, column names in a query are case insensitive by default.  OP could have written select USERID, userid, UserID and all would have worked.

Comment: @codeninja - Have you tried issuing check table and repair table commands?  Where/how are you running the queries?